# Disable a shift-Enter open in Access?

Tags: ms-access-2010

Does anyone know how I can disable a shift-Enter open on an Access 2010 database?
I want to stop users from being able to create and run new queries.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the [*AllowBypassKey*-Property](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AllowBypassKey-Property-30ab5c36-51df-41a0-a955-b0f1deac517b) to your DAO.Database instance and set it to *False*.

But include some way to re-enable the BypassKey for yourself.